# How to reshape dataset (long to wide) having two measurement columns for each category without additional calculations in R

Tags: r

I have this dataset in the long format (see code below to generate this dataset):

```
region   week   average   percent
    A      20         5        30
    A      21         7        40
    A      22        15        50
    B      20         4        15
    B      21         8        27
    B      22         3        11
    ...
```

and I want to prepare it for presentation (HTML with RMarkdown), so I need to convert it to wide having `average` and `percent` for each `week` like this:

```
                 20                 21                  22
region    average  percent   average  percent    average  percent
     A          5       30        7        40         15       50
     B          4       15        8        27          3       11
```

I have explored `dcast`, `dyplr`, `tidyr`, `htmlTable`, and many others without success. I don't need to perform any calculations, just organize the dataset in a different format.

I have done this in the past, but I had to write lots of code. I was wondering if there is an easy way to do it in R.

You can use this code to create the test dataset:

```
region = c( "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B" )
week = c( "20", "21", "22", "20", "21", "22" )
average = c( 5, 7, 15, 4, 8, 3 )
percent = c( 30, 40, 50, 15, 27, 11 )

test = data.frame(
  region,
  week,
  average,
  percent
)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Try with `dcast` `library(data.table);dcast(setDT(test), region ~ week, value.var = c("average", "percent"))`  If you are looking for rmarkdown, check `kable`

Comment: Thank you very much, @akrun. This gets me half way there. It's now just a matter of sorting by the `_week` or just reordering the data frame itself. Thanks again.

Comment: If you want to set the order `j1 <- order(as.numeric(sub(".*_", "", names(out)[-1])));setcolorder(out, names(out)[c(1, j1 + 1)])`

Comment: Thank you very much @akrun. Good stuff. You have no idea of how much time I wasted trying to look for a solution! Thanks again. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using `tidyr`.
It returns a data frame, so the heading won't be grouped.

```
tbl1 <- 
  test %>% 
  gather(var, value, -region, -week) %>% 
  unite(var, week, c("var", "week")) %>% # Combine the week into the variable name
  spread(var, value) # this is the general form you want
```

This is the data_frame that is produced:

```
  region 20_average 20_percent 21_average 21_percent 22_average 22_percent
1      A          5         30          7         40         15         50
2      B          4         15          8         27          3         11
```

Needs to be formatted to look nice in html. My favorite way to do this is using the `htmlTable` package.
Use  this code within a block in Rmd and it will output an html table

````
```{r}
tbl1 %>% 
  htmlTable::htmlTable(rnames = F,
                       cgroup = c("", paste("Week", 20:22)), 
                       n.cgroup = c(1, rep(2, 3)),
                       header = c("Region", rep(c("average", "percent"), 3)))
```
````

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Both answers from @akrun and @Matt L. solve the problem beautifully. @Matt L. is definitely the simplest one. Thank you. I am posting here the solution I came up with based on @akrun's answer. I will definitely use tidyr in my final code.

```
library(htmlTable)
library(data.table)
library(Hmisc)

# Create input (initial) dataset (long)
region = c( "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B" )
week = c( "20", "21", "22", "20", "21", "22" )
average = c( 5, 7, 15, 4, 8, 3 )
percent = c( 30, 40, 50, 15, 27, 11 )

input_ds = data.frame(
  region,
  week,
  average,
  percent
)

# Reshape the dataset into wide, using columns average and percent
# for each week
reshaped_ds = dcast(
  setDT( input_ds ),
  region ~ week,
  value.var = c("average", "percent")
)

# Extract the week number from each column and get a list of indices 
# sorted by week number
col_order <- order(
  as.numeric(
    sub( ".*_", "", names( reshaped_ds )[-1] )
  )
)

# Re-order columns according to col_order
setcolorder(
  reshaped_ds, names(reshaped_ds)[c(1, col_order + 1)]
)

# Prepare the names for group columns
col_group_names = unique(
  paste(
    "Week",
    sub( ".*_", "", names(reshaped_ds)[-1] )
  )
)

# Create another dataset so we don't mess up the reshaped_ds
final_table_ds = reshaped_ds

# Remove '_##' from column names
names( final_table_ds ) = sub(
  "_.*", "", names( final_table_ds )
)

# Capitalize the first letter of each column name
names( final_table_ds ) = capitalize( names( final_table_ds ) )

# Generate the final table in HTML
htmlTable(
  final_table_ds,
  rnames = FALSE,
  cgroup = c( "", col_group_names ),
  n.cgroup = c( 1, rep( 2, length(col_group_names) ) ),
  col.rgroup = c( "none", "#EDEDED" )
)
```

Final output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As the OP mentioned about writing it to a specified format in HTML table, use `kableExtra` after reshaping into 'wide' format

````
---
title: "trial"
author: "akrun"
date: "August 3, 2018"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown



```{r codechunk, echo=FALSE}
library(data.table)

library(kableExtra)
region = c( "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B" )
week = c( "20", "21", "22", "20", "21", "22" )
average = c( 5, 7, 15, 4, 8, 3 )
percent = c( 30, 40, 50, 15, 27, 11 )

test = data.frame(
  region,
  week,
  average,
  percent
)

```


```{r codechunk2, echo=FALSE}
out <- dcast(setDT(test), region ~ week, value.var = c("average", "percent"))
nm1 <- sub(".*_", "", names(out)[-1])
un1 <- unique(nm1)
nm2 <- sub("_.*", "", names(out))
j1 <- order(as.numeric(nm1))
setcolorder(out, names(out)[c(1, j1 + 1)])
setnames(out, nm2[c(1, j1 + 1)])
nm3 <- setNames(rep(2, length(un1)), un1)

```


```{r codechunk3, echo=FALSE}
kable(out, escape = F) %>%
  kable_styling("hover", full_width = F)  %>%
  add_header_above(c(" ", nm3))

```
````

-output

[image]